# 'bundle exec middleman' command fails on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: javascript, ruby, macos, ember.js

I am following step by step what [Ember Guides](https://github.com/emberjs/guides) says about locally configure the project.

I get to install every package manager (Homebrew, Bundler) and builder (Middleman).

But when executing the project (bundle exec middleman), I get an error and server doesn't start:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Pedro:guides pedro$ bundle exec middleman
bundler: failed to load command: middleman (/usr/local/bin/middleman)
LoadError: Could not open library 'c': dlopen(c, 5): image not found.
Could not open library 'libc.dylib': dlopen(libc.dylib, 5): image not found
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/library.rb:133:in `block in ffi_lib'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `ffi_lib'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ethon-0.8.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:8:in `<module:Libc>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ethon-0.8.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:6:in `<module:Ethon>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ethon-0.8.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ethon-0.8.0/lib/ethon.rb:10:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ethon-0.8.0/lib/ethon.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/typhoeus-0.8.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/typhoeus-0.8.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/html-proofer-2.5.2/lib/html/proofer/url_validator.rb:1:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/html-proofer-2.5.2/lib/html/proofer/url_validator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/html-proofer-2.5.2/lib/html/proofer.rb:4:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/html-proofer-2.5.2/lib/html/proofer.rb:4:in `block in require_all'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/html-proofer-2.5.2/lib/html/proofer.rb:3:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/html-proofer-2.5.2/lib/html/proofer.rb:3:in `require_all'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/html-proofer-2.5.2/lib/html/proofer.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:105:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:105:in `rescue in block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/middleman-core-3.4.0/lib/middleman-core/load_paths.rb:37:in `setup_load_paths'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/middleman-core-3.4.0/bin/middleman:10:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/middleman:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/middleman:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: Try to edit `lib/ffi/library.rb` in installed ffi gem. Replace `LIBC = FFI::Platform::LIBC` string with `LIBC = '/usr/lib/libc.dylib'`. There is full discussion: https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/461

Comment: Thanks a lot! It shown me the way. Just replacing that line didn't do it for me. I got stuck in another error (couldn't find libcurl.dylib). So I followed the piece of advice that said to download the 'elcapt' branch. I got from there the library.rb file and substituted it in my local Ruby installation. May be not the most elegant way to solve it, but it did it for me :). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Solved! As Yevgeniy Anfilofyev said in a comment, there is a full discussion [here](http://%20github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/461).

Following that issue, what I finally did was to replace the [library.rb file content from the elcapt branch in the ffi/ffi project](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/blob/master/lib/ffi/library.rb).

This might not be the most elegant way to solve it, but it did it for me.

Other developers did what Yevgeniy mentioned in his comment and it was enough. Just replace the value of a variable in that file: Replace LIBC = FFI::Platform::LIBC string with LIBC = '/usr/lib/libc.dylib'.